# Win32 can't uniquely identify a Microsoft Edge window

Tags: winapi, blueprism

Win32 mapper in Blue Prism can't uniquely identify an Edge window in Blue Prism. Has anyone encountered this problem before.

Comment: The answer to this question is either *"yes"* or *"no"*. Are you sure that's the question you meant to ask?

Comment: If they encountered this problem then they might know how to solve it

Comment: Why don't you ask that question then?

Comment: Can you provide a LITTLE more insight into things like what was provided by the mapper, what have you tried yourself manually to attach etc.

Comment: To add, every time I use applications I can struggle to get unique windows its incredibly common, then you refine it to get it unique. But thats a standard process, we need some more details to at least understand what you've done to understand what isn't working for you

Comment: I can maximize and Minimize from running the Action. I can identify the Edge Window. I can't maximize and minimize when ran from control room or the step out feature. I have applied long waits after the actions before the minimize to make sure the screen is in the right format for minimizing.

Comment: instead of long waits can you add wait stages that confirm the elements exist before acting on them? like wait stage condition check window exists then perform an action on that element? ie element being actioned and element in the wait stage are correct?